# Excel VBA: huge cells copy and get 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba

I had a source excel with strings ,the number is 9000 rows and 20 columns , and I need to copy them to a new sheet , when i debug it I always get 1004 error:

But I do need the Range can be variable .... ,so this workable makes no sense.

Can some experts give a hand ?

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the start of your module.  You will see the errors. Your first three declaration statements are wrong syntax.

Comment: What’s the value of G_F_RowNum when it fails?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the problems with declarations that @RonRosenfeld has pointed out, you are writing statements that are intrinsically hard to debug:

Things like

```
Set tRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(C_MY_Sheet_Backlog).Range("A2").Resize(G_FBP_RowNum - 7, 1)
```

are hard to debug since it is difficult to tell what part of the statement is causing the trouble. Break it into 3 lines (with one dot operator per line) and see which line fails first:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(C_MY_Sheet_Backlog)
Set tRng = WS.Range("A2")
Set tRng = tRng.Resize(G_F_RowNum - 7, 1)
```

That should focus your debugging efforts. The middle `Set` is almost certainly not the problem so you probably could combine the last two sets into one. I suspect that the final one is. In general, this way of decomposing a compound method invocation into simpler method invocations is a useful debugging strategy.

Also -- dont use `Integer`. It risks overflow for no reason. Use `Long` instead.